# Writing to a mutex'ed shared resourced

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, pthreads, mutex

I've a C++ list which is being processed by multiple thread.

Each thread creates a `pthread_mutex_lock` on the list so that other threads cannot "interfere" with the list.  As a part of processing, each thread also `push_back` data on the list.

My question is - is `push_back` on a mutex-ed list a bad idea? Is the mutex still valid while the thread is pusing more data on the list?  Most of the documentation/examples I've seen on `pthread_mutex_lock` are only doing "reading" so I am curious to know what happens the same thread which acquired lock, writes on the shared resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as only that particular thread is holding the lock, and no other thread can take this lock, writing should be fine. think of why a problem could happen? it wouldve been a problem if one thread was writing and the other was reading simultaneously. If a ball is yours, you can do anything with it right? things change when they're shared.

Answer (score 0):

The mutex needs to be unique for the entire group of threads (i.e. all threads must use the same mutex). If you create a mutex for each thread, then you are not thread-safe at all, because each thread will wait on its own mutex and not be synchronized with the rest.

And yes an acquired mutex can be used safely to both read and write.